# Atmel WINC1500 - TCP Sockets

Tags: tcp, wifi, packet, atmel

I am currently working with ATMEL's WINC1500 wifi module on their SAMD21 XPLained development kit.

I am trying to send around 20-40 TCP packets a second (the size doesn't seem to matter in my problem).

What is happening is that when the WINC1500 is in AP mode as a TCP server, once a socket connection is made and I start sending packets across. There are very noticeable stalls in the WINC1500 where the module seems to stop sending TCP packets for around .5 of a second. However receiving packets still run fine.

Because of the rate I am sending packets, the WINC1500 will eventually run out of memory to store my messages I am passing onto it and will returns a BUFFER FULL error and then after the .5 second stall all the messages will send at once (but those that returned the buffer error is lost).

To me it seems like it is a WINC1500 firmware issue, but was wondering if anyone with experience in this chip, or in WiFi/TCP packets in general that could shed some light on where the problem might be?

I have been in contact with Atmel support but it is slow.

Comment: The TCP in the device should issue window-shrinks and ultimately zero-windows, which will stop the sender from sending. It should not just run out of memory.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I am thinking it is not a directly a TCP related issue as it can still receive information through the same socket. I am 98% certain that the WINC1500 firmware is just refusing to send for some reason for .5 second at a time.

Comment: I know this is a super old thread, but two things: First,  update the WINC firmware.   v19.7.7 works much better than the v15 vintage code.  Second, the serial port on the WINC emits useful diagnostic data (at 460800 baud!) -- this can give you insights as to what's going on.